# How can I resolve the following xmlns MSBuild error?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015, build-error

I have a .NET Standard 4.7.2 solution that builds locally just fine. On trying to run a CI build in TFS 2015 sp3, I am seeing the following error. I tried the prescribed change, adding the xmlns value to each project in the solution, but the error still occurs. **How can I resolve this, please?**

```
The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.
```

Thanks much.

Comment: Is your local environment the same as the build agent machine, like VS version and msbuild version? Please login your build agent machine, navigate to the agent working folder, and build the project with msbuild command line to see how's the result.

Comment: Thank you Cece. Apparently, the Microsoft.Net.Compilers v3.8.0 nuget package got added to the solution (not sure how...) and was overriding the TFS MSBuild agent. I removed the package and things are building again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Microsoft.Net.Compilers v3.8.0 nuget package got added to the solution (not sure how...) and was overriding the TFS MSBuild agent. I removed the package and things are building again

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the solution can be built successfully on the build agent machine. Please login your build agent machine, navigate to the agent working folder, and build the project with msbuild command line to see how's the result.

Also, make sure your local environment the same as the build agent machine, like VS version and msbuild version. You could clean the agent working folder and have another try.